# Set CSS background-image without effecting page height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am loading a page into an iframe. The source for the iframe has a CSS setting to set the background image:

```
body {
    background: url("//mydomain.com/bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
}
```

The image has a height of 1586px. It must be the background of all pages (there are a bout 6) and it cannot be scaled. If a page is less than 1586px in height then the background image should be cropped.

My problem is that the iframe is always 1586px in height even though the page (src=) is much shorter. I've tried overflow:hidden but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try  background-size: cover?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Maybe try

```
body {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If that doesn't work try selecting `html, body` opposed to just `body`.

Comment: Hadn't tried height: auto and thought that was going to work, but it didn't make any difference. I used your 3 lines of code with html,body.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../bg.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```